# FocusFollowsMouse, cut-paste from browser to Terminal in 10.8 (duplicate)

Tags: macos, terminal, mouse

Added: this was discussed in
[focus-follows-mouse-plus-auto-raise-on-mac-os-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98310/focus-follows-mouse-plus-auto-raise-on-mac-os-x) on SO in 2010. In short, accept it,
or buy an addon:
[how-can-i-make-focus-follow-the-mouse-cursor](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-can-i-make-focus-follow-the-mouse-cursor).

---

The sequence:

1. cut text in a browser window (mouse swipe, ⌘ C: "Edit" blinks)
2. move the mouse to a Terminal window (cursor goes solid)
3. click in the Terminal window -- **necessary in 10.8.3, not in 10.4 ?**
4. paste, ⌘ V

works only with "click in Terminal" on my new iMac 10.8.3.
On a 10.4 iMac though, ⌘ C - move mouse - ⌘ V works without the extra click.

Has FocusFollowsMouse changed in 10.8, or is it just me ?  I have

```
defaults write com.apple.Terminal FocusFollowsMouse -string YES

defaults read | grep -i mouse -->

    "com.apple.mouse.scaling" = 1;
                    default = "Time Profile App Under Mouse";
                NSMessage = timeProfileUnderMouse;
    FocusFollowsMouse = YES;
"com.apple.driver.AppleBluetoothMultitouch.mouse" =     {
    MouseButtonDivision = 55;
    MouseButtonMode = OneButton;
    MouseHorizontalScroll = 1;
    MouseMomentumScroll = 1;
    MouseTwoFingerDoubleTapGesture = 3;
    MouseTwoFingerHorizSwipeGesture = 2;
    MouseVerticalScroll = 1;
    USBMouseStopsTrackpad = 0;
"com.apple.driver.AppleHIDMouse" =     {
```

If it matters, the mouse is a cable mouse, TERM = vt100.

Comment: FWIW, Terminal behaves the same way for me in 10.8, and iTerm 2 also requires clicking the window first.

Comment: I don't recall `FocusFollowsMouse` sending Command keys to the terminal in previous versions. Command keys are usually only sent to the frontmost application, even if a background window has keyboard focus for normal input.

Comment: Note that your `defaults` command is incorrect: replace `-string` with `-bool` (although some applications will figure out that the string "YES" should be treated like boolean YES, you must not rely on it).