# Whats the most efficient way to switch between 2 open windows on OSX ? (OR What am I doing wrong ?)

Tags: macos, windows

I've recently transitioned to using OSX after using windows/linux for the last 14 years. Few things I like, few things I can't come to terms with. The biggest gripe is active window management on OSX.

Scenario : 2 windows open side by side. Say one of them is a chat. Another is a turn based card game.

Action : Click on a control object of the passive window

In Windows, 2 things happen seamlessly. The window becomes active AND the control gets activated.

In OSX, with the same action, the window becomes active sometimes (depends on which application's window it is). Sometimes it doesn't get activated until you click on that windows titlebar (Happens a lot with the mail app). And then, only after it is activated, I can interact with anything inside that window.

This behaviour pisses me off. This, combined with the fact that there is no window snap available by default. (I installed BTT for this. Works well) 
I am ready to unlearn the way I handle windows in Windows if OSX provides a more efficient way of working on 2 applications at the same time. Anybody ?

I have a 15 inch retina macbook pro with OSX 10.10.5

Comment: With the keyboard 'CMB + TAB' or with the pad '4 fingers on the (right / left)' ?

Comment: Read my question completely. I am not asking to switch between windows that are otherwise not visible. Both the windows are completely visible. I just need to be able to multitask with them without having to activate one before using it.

Comment: On apps that I am using this does not seem to happen.    What apps are you trying it on?

Comment: Ohhh, what is your chat app ? Did you tried with some others one ? From my point of view your chat app, simply don't use multitasking...

Comment: Happening With Google Chrome, Mail, Finder, Calender, System preferences, Quicktime. I am sure its not app specific, I wish I could record my screen to explain my annoyance. Mail is the biggest culprit. Its not in the same league as the other osx apps. Its very laggy. So having this problem + lag is even worse.
@Joop Do you mean to say that you can click on a button in the inactive window and it clicks on the first go ??

Comment: ok see what you mean now.   was switching between two windows with op en text dialogues that works fine.   See what you mean and difference between how windows behaves.   Never bothered me.    Think it is switcher expectations.    for me hovering over non active window and trying to scroll in windows does the incorrect thing.   Looks like it is mainly happening in mail.   Admit that it is irritating.

Comment: See your point,  but I have always thought of one click to change focus then start working.    Paradigm shift.   I can see how you like windows behaviour.   I switched years ago and do not notice it.    In fact could be seen as possitive as sometimes you have overlapping windows.    being able to click anythere in it and bring it to foreground is wanted behaviour.   If spot had link on could be unwanted.   maybe there is a terminal hack/setting that can change this behaviour though.

Comment: haven't tried this but this seems to do something like your are looking for:   https://wuhrr.wordpress.com/2008/08/25/switching-between-os-x-terminal-windows/

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to enable "focus follows mouse" discussed here: 
[How can I make focus follow the mouse cursor?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-can-i-make-focus-follow-the-mouse-cursor), but that might be more than you want...

Otherwise I second MrMojoRisin, get used to cmd+tab or 4 finger swipe (you need BetterTouchTool on Yosemite to bring this last one back).