# Focus follows mouse (and autoraise) for Chrome windows

Tags: google-chrome, mouse, window-manager, cursor

Is there a way to enable focus-follows-mouse behavior for Google Chrome windows? The desired behavior is that if there are two browser windows, occupying the left and right halves of the screen, then moving the mouse from the left half of the screen to the right half of the screen would change focus from the left browser window to the right.

I looked at [How can I make focus follow the mouse cursor?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-can-i-make-focus-follow-the-mouse-cursor) but the solutions didn't seem satisfactory. One worked only for X11 apps and terminal, and another suggested using Zooom/2 (which is now defunct). Since I only care about getting this working for Google Chrome windows, does anyone know if there is a way to do this using a simple extension or add-on?

As a bonus, it would be nice if I could get this working on Mavericks.

I have given up on getting universal focus-follows-mouse behavior, although if you have a solution to this more general problem that would be even better...

---

Due to lack of responses, I have cross-posted this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336156/focus-follows-mouse-for-google-chrome-on-macos).

UPDATE: I have posted a slight variant of this question [on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1199493/focus-follows-mouse-for-google-chrome-on-macos) as well, after another day with no answers.

Comment: Uhhh you use Linux and dual boot.  Mac has never had this feature that I'm aware.

Comment: It is clear from the question that I am looking for a native solution on macOS. Thanks for the suggestion, regardless of how obvious it is.

Comment: Couldn't you run chrome on X11 then?  Video playback would be terrible but it would work.

Comment: Can you expand this into an answer? (I.e., clarify what exactly you mean by "running chrome on X11")

Comment: I do have a mac so maybe.  You want which OS?  I'm running el captain not mavericks but I think I can fix that with a quick install on my hard drive.  The basic task would be to install ubuntu or some operating system on virtual box or VMware and then run it through X11.

Comment: As I mentioned in response to your first comment, I am looking for native solutions. That being said, there do exist apps that run using X11 on macOS without relying on virtual box or VMWare, for example inkscape. But no, I am not looking for a solution that just runs Chrome in Ubuntu under an emulator.